# Binding data to ListView for Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

I hope some can help me with this one as its driving me mad. I am writing a prototype app for a project at work and its also my first Windows 8 app as well. All I am trying to do is get a ListView control to display some information from a collection, I've included all the code below. I can't seem to get it to work with the collection that I actually want to display but if I make a test class and collection I can display that fine, code also included. I'm totally perplexed by this one so it must be something obvious I'm missing, probably not seeing the wood for the trees.

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Test Code (Works fine):

Code Behind:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

private List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var people = new List<Person>();

        people.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "John", Surname = "Smith" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "Tom", Surname = "Jones" });
        people.Add(new Person() { Firstname = "Barry", Surname = "Thomas" });

        return people;
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        OrdersListView.DataContext = this.GetPeople();
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <ListView x:Name="OrdersListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name: " Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" Margin="2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Actual Code (Displays Nothing):

Code Behind:

```
private async Task<List<Order>> LoadData()
    {
        const string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:54879/";

        var client = new HttpClient
                     {
                         BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl)
                     };

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/orders");
        var orders = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Order[]>();

        return orders.ToList();
    }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        OrdersListView.DataContext = this.LoadData();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="OrdersListView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="auto" Height="auto">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Order Ref: " Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderReference}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Name: " Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Address: " Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address1}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address2}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TownCity}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Country}" Margin="2" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Postcode}" Margin="2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to put `await` on `LoadData()` to set the `DataContext` as the result of the `Task`.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    OrdersListView.DataContext = await this.LoadData();
}
```

Comment: ARGH! Of course it does! I said it would be something obvious. Thanks for that nit.